# how to display an entire table as a "legend" on the access form

Tags: ms-access

I have an invoice form which pulls in multiple interrelated tables.  But separately from that, I want to display a "legend" at the bottom of the invoice.  The legend is contents of a separate table, but its not really related to anything on the form.  It is simply some "verbiage" the source for which originates out of a access table.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a subform, bound to that separate table, in the form footer.

You may even get away with, in design view, to simply drag the table and drop it in the form footer.

Comment: I have tried that -- so what I get is a vertical table of codes and descriptions. Is it possible to get rid of headings? Is it possible to make data "flow" into 3 columns that occupy the entire width of the form?  It about 30 entries -- I cant simply display it vertically -- it needs to display lets say 3 columns, 10 entries each.  Thank you

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Design a custom form using as source a custom query that concatenate rows and/or fields as you prefer. Bing/Google on that.